# Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query Not giving me the results I want

Tags: 2010, search, custom

I'm currently working on creating a custom search page built from scratch, and thus I'm trying to query our site for keywords.

I have set-up the SharePoint Foundation Search on Central Admin and I can see the search works fine when I use the default search page that SharePoint comes with.

But when I try query the results in C# using KeywordQuery I get no results back and when I try and use the FullTextSqlQuery I get an error "Scope in your query does not exist."

Here is a sample of my code for both the keywordQuery and the FullTextSQLQuery

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query.KeywordQuery myQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(site);
                myQuery.QueryText = tag;

                try
                {
                    ResultTableCollection queryResults = myQuery.Execute();

                    if (queryResults.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataTable retResults = new DataTable();
                        using (ResultTable relevantResults = queryResults[ResultType.RelevantResults])
                            retResults.Load(relevantResults, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);



FullTextSqlQuery myQuery = new FullTextSqlQuery(site)
                {
                    QueryText = String.Format("SELECT Title, SiteName, Path FROM Scope() WHERE \"scope\"='All Sites' AND CONTAINS('\"{0}\"')", tag),
                    //QueryText = String.Format("SELECT Title, SiteName, Path FROM Scope()", searchPhrase),
                    TrimDuplicates = true,
                    StartRow = 0,
                    RowLimit = 200,
                    ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults
                    //IgnoreAllNoiseQuery = false
                };

                ResultTableCollection queryResults = myQuery.Execute();

                if (queryResults.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTable retResults = new DataTable();
                    using (ResultTable relevantResults = queryResults[ResultType.RelevantResults])
                        retResults.Load(relevantResults, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

Can you guys please help me figure out what the issue is?

Edit:
issue fixed, for the FullTextSqlQuery it turned out my QueryText was not right.

This is the right format 
 QueryText = String.Format("SELECT Title, Path FROM Scope() WHERE CONTAINS('{0}')", tag),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link about an issue with the managed property SiteName.  This might be the isse, have you tried to query for just Title?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/90244999-2a5d-43fa-9915-c44f2bd2d1a0/

Also, CONTAINS('\"{0}\"')" here are you trying to search for "tag" or tag. Single quotes are enough, here is the link for syntax:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms513993.aspx

Comment: Also, CONTAINS('\"{0}\"')" here are you trying to search for "tag" or tag. Single quotes are enough, here is the link for syntax:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms513993.aspx

Comment: Thanks, your answer lead me in the right direction.
The correct QueryText is
QueryText = String.Format("SELECT Title, Path FROM Scope() WHERE CONTAINS('{0}')", tag),

Answer (score 1):

Actually the correct managed property that you need to use in your query is called: 'SiteTitle'
'ows_SiteName' is the crawled property.

So your query will look something like:

QueryText = String.Format("SELECT Title, SiteTitle, Path FROM Scope() ")

Answer (score 0):

I know I am not directly helping but this site may help. http://sharepointsearchserv.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have taken a look at that before, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work. Is there any tutorial on how to use it?